# Calculating the definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let:

$$ A = \int_0^1 \frac{e^t}{1+t} dt$$

Then what is the value of:

$$ \int_{a-1}^a \frac{e^{-t}}{t-a-1} dt$$

I tried using the property:

$$ \int_a^b f(x) dx =\int_a^b f(a+b-x) dx$$

But that was of no help

Comment: You want it in terms of $A$?

Comment: Yeah, in terms of 'A' and 'a'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make the substitution $t = a-u$. This gives you:

$\displaystyle\int_{a-1}^{a}\dfrac{e^{-t}}{t-a-1}\,dt = \int_{1}^{0}\dfrac{e^{-(a-u)}}{(a-u)-a-1} \cdot -1\,du = \int_{1}^{0}\dfrac{e^{-a} \cdot e^{u}}{u+1}\,du$

Do you see how to relate this to the original integral $A = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{e^u}{1+u}\,du$?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Notice, $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^t}{1+t}dt$$ Let $1+t=u\implies dt=du$
$$\int_{1}^{2}\frac{e^{u-1}}{u}du$$

I hope you may proceed further